# The supplied auth credential is malformed, has expired or is not currently supported. When sign in with LINE through Firebase

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I logged in using LINE with the code below

```
  Future<UserCredential?> signIn() async {
    try {
      final result =
          await LineSDK.instance.login(scopes: ["profile", "openid", "email"]);

      final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("LINE").credential(
          accessToken: result.accessToken.idTokenRaw, signInMethod: 'LINE');
      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

But I got exception `[firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed, has expired or is not currently supported.` when execute `return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);`

and there is another log I don't know if it's related `[connection] nw_connection_copy_metadata_block_invoke [C54] Client called nw_connection_copy_metadata on unconnected nw_connection Support for an auth provider with identifier 'LINE' is not implemented.`

I have enabled LINE Provider in Firebase
[image]

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  firebase_auth: ^4.13.0
  flutter_line_sdk: ^2.3.5
```

Comment: Looks like I'm using firebase's OIDC. But I still don't know how to sign in with Firebase

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, in my case, the problem was that I wrote down the wrong client ID.

[image]

Also, check the provider ID.

I used "kakao", and "oidc.kakao" was the provider ID.
So... fix "LINE" to "line" in firebase and code:

```dart
OAuthProvider("LINE")
```

to

```
OAuthProvider("oidc.line")
```

[image]